# Create SOS signal using Java.Util.Timer

Tags: java, android, timer, led

I want to create an android app that performs the SOS signal using the flashlight on the phone and I know how to control the flash light.

This is what I want the flash light to do:

```
1) Flash light on for 1 second
2) Flash light off for 1 second
3) Flash light on for 1 second
4) Flash light off for 1 second
5) Flash light on for 1 second
6) Flash light off for 1 second

7) Flash light on for 3 seconds
8) Flash light off for 1 second
9) Flash light on for 3 seconds
10) Flash light off for 1 second
11) Flash light on for 3 seconds
12) Flash light off for 1 second

13) Flash light on for 1 second
14) Flash light off for 1 second
15) Flash light on for 1 second
16) Flash light off for 1 second
17) Flash light on for 1 second
18) Flash light off for 1 second
```

How can I accomplish this using the timer class in java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach for this would be to create a class with all definitions of the alphabet and their equivalent in Morse Code. Numbers can be added as well. That way you can even enter any text, not just SOS.

If SOS is your only goal, then creating a class might be an overkill but still good practice.

Have a look at the docs for Timer class

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html << Updated Link

This is the method I used from the timer class in the example below. So for your SOS you could quite possible add a forloop to run the sequence for so many seconds, and also control your LED light.

```
public void schedule(TimerTask task,
            long delay,
            long period)
```

//Usage of timer

import java.util.*;

public class TimerDemo {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // declare and create task
    TimerTask taskNew = new TimerTask() {
        // runs our task
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Timer running...");

        }
    };
    // declare and create timer
    Timer myTimer = new Timer();


    /* schedule the timer (task scheduled, delay in ms before task is
     * execution, period in ms between successive tasks executions
     */
    myTimer.schedule(taskNew, 500, 1000);

}
```

}

I hope this gives a better example.

Comment: How is this answer constructive? The OP asks how to use the `Timer` class and you never actually give any info on that, save for 2 links - one to a severely outdated Javadoc (Does anyone even use Java 5 anymore?), and another to a simple code snippet with no explanation that does something quite different. Plus this answer will be pretty useless if and once the link goes dead.

Comment: I'm no expert, but looking at those timer examples, it gives a pretty clear idea how to use timer. I guess I'll just have write some usage as well and well I'm at it write the whole thing. I'll update links to newer api ASAP. Thanks for your constructive comment. Just love SO I thought this forum was to help people, not to babyseat. If he showed some timer code, then I can extend my answer.

Comment: The thing about just providing a link is that it might be dead next year. Or maybe just offline for a day when someone really needs it. The purpose of an SO answer is to be useful on it's own. Giving a link as an extra is perfectly fine, but you'd need to provide at least a short explanation/summary of the contents for this to be a good answer.

Comment: Totally understandable, next time I'll think about that when writing answers.